# Compiling SFML project

Tags: linux, linker, g++, sfml

I try to build a project with SFML 2.0

g++ src/*.cpp -o test -L./SFML-2.0/lib/ -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window

And I got undefined references on everything coming from SFML.

Thanks

EDIT: I tried to first compile my sources with -c option, it compiles, but when I launch it, g++ tells me he doesnt find libsfml-window.so.1.6 - The problem is that I'm not using 1.6 at all...

EDIT2: By the way, SFML-2.0 has no Makefile in it

Comment: There are tutorials on SFML's website about how to install or compile it, they contain everything you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Make sure you get SFML 2.0 itself.

Many of the Linux distros still use SFML 1.6 in their package manager, so you'll have to compiler SFML on your own.

- SFML uses [CMake](http://cmake.org/) to generate make or project files.

There's a [tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/compile-with-cmake.php) explain exactly how to build SFML from source with CMake.

- How to build your project with SFML on Linux has its own [tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-linux.php).

SFML's graphics and window module build on top of the system module, thus you'll have to link against that as well. You need to make sure the compiler gets SFML's header files as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have sfml installed correctly

   Sudo apt-get install libsfml-dev

I believe is the correct install.

2. You need to link sfml-graphics sfml-window and sfml-system in most scenarios